# mq_notify not notifying about an event (Linux programming)

Tags: c, linux, posix, ipc, message-queue

I'm using `mq_notify` to be notified about events on a message queue, but my registered notifier function is not being called.  Did I miss something?

I'm pasting my code snippet below:

---

```
static void sigNotifier(union sigval sv)
{
   printf ("I'm called.\n");
}    

int main()
{
   mqd_t queueID = 0;
   message_t msg;
   int retval;
   struct mq_attr attr;
   struct sigevent sev;

   attr.mq_msgsize = MSG_SIZE;
   attr.mq_maxmsg = 30;

   errno = 0;

   queueID = mq_open(MSG_QUEUE_NAME, O_RDONLY, 0666, &attr);

   if (queueID == -1) {
      printf ("Message queue open failed: %d\n", errno);
   }

   sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
   sev.sigev_notify_function = sigNotifier;
   sev.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
   sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &queueID;

   retval = mq_notify(queueID, &sev);
   if (retval < 0) {
      printf ("Notification failed: %d\n", errno);
   }

   while (1);    
}
```

Comment: `struct mq_attr attr = {0}; and struct sigevent sev = {0}; ` do that make any difference ? you're not initalizing every field in those structures, you could be passing garbage values around.

Answer (score 2):

Man Page **mq_notify**:

1) Message notification occurs only when a new message arrives and the queue was previously empty. If the queue was not empty at the time mq_notify() was called, then a notification will occur only after the queue is emptied and a new message arrives.

2) Notification occurs once: after a notification is delivered, the notification registration is removed, and another process can register for message notification.  If the notified process wishes to receive the next notification, it can use mq_notify() to request a further notification.

3) Only one process can be registered to receive notification from a message queue.

So:

1) Empty the MsgQ to recv new messages in the reader process immediately after registering with mq_notify().

2) Re-register in the notify function for receiving next message.

3) Register only 1 process for receiving messages from Q.

Here is a simple message queue reader code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;

#define MSG_Q_NAME "/MY_MSGQ_3"

static void                     /* Thread start function */
tfunc(union sigval sv)
{
  mqd_t msq_id = *(static_cast<mqd_t*>(sv.sival_ptr));

  struct mq_attr attr;
  if(mq_getattr(msq_id, &attr) < 0)
  {
    cout << "Error in mq_getattr " << strerror(errno)  << endl;
    return;
  }

  // Reregister for new messages on Q
  struct sigevent sev;
  sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
  sev.sigev_notify_function = tfunc;
  sev.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
  sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = sv.sival_ptr;
  if (mq_notify(msq_id, &sev) < 0)
  {
    cout << "Error during Reregister in msq_notify : "
         << strerror(errno) << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Read new message on the Q
  char* arr = new char[attr.mq_msgsize];
  memset(arr, 0, attr.mq_msgsize);
  if(mq_receive(msq_id, arr, attr.mq_msgsize, 0) < 0)
  {
    if(errno != EAGAIN)
    {
      cout << "Error in mq_receive " << strerror(errno) << endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Msg rcvd " << arr << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  mqd_t msq_id = mq_open(MSG_Q_NAME, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK | O_CREAT, 0666, 0);
  if(msq_id == (mqd_t) -1)
  {
    cout << "Error on msg Q creation: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // The process is registered for notification for new message on the Q
  struct sigevent sev;
  sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
  sev.sigev_notify_function = tfunc;
  sev.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
  sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &msq_id;

  if (mq_notify(msq_id, &sev) < 0)
  {
    cout << "Error on msg Q notify : " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Notify for msg Q reception " << MSG_Q_NAME << endl;
  }

  // Man Page mq_notify: Message notification occurs only when a new
  // message arrives and the queue was previously empty. If the queue was
  // not empty at the time mq_notify() was called, then a notification will
  // occur only after the queue is emptied and a new message arrives.
  //
  // So emptying the Q to recv new messages
  ssize_t n = 0;
  struct mq_attr attr;
  if(mq_getattr(msq_id, &attr) < 0)
  {
    cout << "Error in mq_getattr " << strerror(errno)  << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  char* arr = new char[attr.mq_msgsize];
  memset(arr, 0, attr.mq_msgsize);
  while((n = mq_receive(msq_id, arr, attr.mq_msgsize, 0) >= 0))
  {
    cout << "Empty the Q. Msg rcvd " << arr << endl;
  }

  while(1)
    ;

  mq_close(msq_id);
}
```

Here is a simple message Q writer code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 

using namespace std;

#define MSG_Q_NAME "/MY_MSGQ_3"

int main()
{
  struct mq_attr attr;
  memset(&attr, 0, sizeof attr);
  attr.mq_msgsize = 8192;
  attr.mq_flags = 0;
  attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;

  mqd_t msq_id = mq_open(MSG_Q_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_NONBLOCK,
                         0777, &attr);
  if(msq_id == (mqd_t) -1)
  {
    cout << "Error on msg Q creation: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  // Write 5 msgs on message Q
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    stringstream s;
    s << "My Msg " << i;

    if(mq_send(msq_id, s.str().c_str(), strlen(s.str().c_str()), 0) < 0)
    {
      if(errno != EAGAIN)
      {
        cout << "Error on sending msg on MsgQ " << strerror(errno);
        mq_close(msq_id);
        exit(1);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "Sent msg " << s.str() << endl;
    }

    sleep(1); // Easily see the received message in reader
  }

  mq_close(msq_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the code is copies from man page I would ask:

1. Are you sure you sending message to queue correctly?
2. Try first to read using blocking read and see if you get something.

Under Linux you can use select/poll/epoll to wait for notifications about queue as well as
mqd_t is ordinary file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if the Queue already has messages. If messages exist on the queue then mq_notify() would not get notification untill the queue is empty and then new messages come in. 
Since the queue is a persistent across program runs you want to make sure the mq_unlink() is already called on the queue before open.